# Total Share Count

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the total count of all the shares for my WordPress Blog. I googled and found this little script but its not counting all shares properly.

```
<?php
function get_shares($url) {    
  $json_string = file_get_contents("http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=$url&format=json");
  $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
  return intval( $json['count'] );
}
function get_tweets($url) {

    $json_string = file_get_contents('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url);
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);

    return intval( $json['count'] );
}

function get_likes($url) {

    $json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);

    return intval( $json[$url]['shares'] );
}

function get_plusones($url) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    $curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);

    $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);

    return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
}
function total($url){
    return get_tweets($url) + get_shares($url) + get_likes($url) + get_plusones($url); }
?>


<span class="pm-label"><?php echo total("http://pypix.com/roundups/best-python-2013/"); ?>
                                    Share</span>
```

This script counts 214 shares as total but actual is 417 shares.

Please help guys.﻿

Comment: Use only one count at a time, which one doesn't read the data properly?

Comment: Google Plus share count is not counting properly.

Comment: As a side note, you should cache your `counts` using Transient API (http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this option to curl:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This should make google plus working. Answer found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321202/difficulty-getting-google-plus-one-count):

Comment: Awesome, this trick worked. But now getting different error



`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_shares() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\pypix_new\index.php:54) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\pypix_new\index.php on line 54`